# Move AD user based on their employeeID in csv file

Tags: powershell, csv, move

I'm attempting to move AD users to different ou's based on a CSV file of employee numbers.  I've searched around and I have found a suggestion and tried this code:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$TargetOU = "OU=Math,OU=Students,DC=domain,DC=net"
$IDs = Import-CSV "c:\testids.csv" | Select -ExpandProperty employeeID
Get-ADUser -filter * -Properties employeeID | Where { $IDs -contains $_.employeeID } | 
Move-ADObject -TargetPath $TargetOU
```

My csv file looks like this

```
employeeID
11111
22222
33333
```

It runs with no errors. But the users never move.  Im running Server 2012R2.

Any suggestions?  Am I on the wrong track or completely off in left field?

Comment: Does your AD attribute or you CSV contain trailing or leading spaces? That would be the first thing I would check as either would cause this issue.

Comment: @matt ive checked and no spaces.

Comment: Does `$ids` look like it contains the right content?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$TargetOU = "OU=Math,OU=Students,DC=domain,DC=net"

$IDs = Import-CSV "c:\testids.csv" | Select employeeID

$IDs | % { Get-ADUser -Filter { employeeID -eq $_.employeeID } -Property employeeID |
Move-ADObject -TargetPath $TargetOU }
```

Sorry, I pushed 'Enter' too quickly. This has your CSV saved as the $IDs object before you start. I think your pipes were a little out of order. Let me know if this works, and if it doesn't I'll try again.

Comment: This is preferable to using `-Filter *`.

Comment: @Chris I get an error "Get-ADUser : Property: 'employeeID' not found in object of type: 'System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject'.
At line:7 char:12"  Any ideas?

Comment: Whoops. Add the -Property employeeID to the Get-ADUser cmdlet.

Comment: @ChrisMartin I added -Property and ran an still users do not change ou.  I also tried  Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter { employeeID -eq $_.employeeID }.  The script completes with no errors but they dont move either.  Any suggestions?  Thanks for all your help!

Comment: @ShawnIT Answer my comment. We need to check that your input file is well formed. What is the output of `$IDs` and then `$IDs | % { Get-ADUser -Filter { employeeID -eq $_.employeeID }` on their own?

Comment: Try adding -Confirm:$false to the end of the Move-ADObject cmdlet

Comment: @ChrisMartin my hunch is something here is null. I doubt `Move-ADObject` is being called

Comment: @Matt Sorry I overlooked your comment above.  When I call $IDs I get the output of my csv returned after each.  Im starting to think maybe a permission issue?  The user running the script is an domain admin.  Should there be other permissions assigned?

Comment: @ShawnIT can we see the contents of $IDs once $IDs = Import-Csv... has been run? Feel free to mock up an input as long as it has the same structure

Comment: @ShawnIT what about the get-aduser calls? do they work?

Comment: @ChrisMartin when I edit line to read "Move-ADObject -TargetPath $TargetOU -Confirm: $false" my script completes without any error but the users dont move ou's

Comment: By completes without any error, you mean mission accomplished? Or it runs, but nothing moves still?

Comment: @Matt What could I add to verify that they work?  My minds gone blank at this point.  Again thanks for your help!

Comment: @ChrisMartin Users still dont move.

Comment: This was not right at all. Sorry. If this isn't done tomorrow I'll have a look at work, I've left since I first answered this question and don't have AD in front of me.

Comment: @ShawnIT Pick an employeeID from your list, then run Get-ADUser -Filter {EmployeeID -eq <YOURNUMBER>} -Properties EmployeeID    and see if you get a result.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'm on the bandwagon of I want to be sure your finding the correct users first. Theory being that `Move-ADObject` is not getting any input.

First I would do this to check the CSV file contents.

```
Get-Content "c:\testids.csv" | Select -Skip 1 | ForEach-Object{"'$_'"}
```

Then assuming that is working what is the result of this command?

```
$IDs | ForEach-Object{Get-ADUser -Filter  "employeeID -eq '$_'" -Property employeeID
```

**Update from Comments**

I wonder now if you are looking at the wrong AD Attribute. Maybe it should be `EmployeeNumber`.

```
$IDs | ForEach-Object{Get-ADUser -Filter  "employeeNumber -eq '$_'" -Property employeeNumber
```

Give that a try and see if that is what you need?

Also should try and verify that you have no white-space or special characters in the actual `employeeid`

```
"'$(Get-Aduser accountthathasid -properties employeeid | select -expand employeeid)'"
```

Comment: after I run the first line I return the following '10312' which is correct.  That is the only entry in the csv file.  So then I change that line to IDs=Get-Content "c:\testids.csv" | Select -Skip 1 | ForEach-Object{"'$_'"} then add line $IDs | ForEach-Object{Get-ADUser -Filter  {employeeID -eq '$_'} -Property employeeID }.  Then I run it.  I get no output.  Did I do something wrong.  I did have to change the format a little because I got an error if I copied line exact.

Comment: Dont use the brackets use: `Get-ADUser -Filter "employeeID -eq '$_'" -Property employeeID` if that does not work what is the output of `Get-ADUser -Filter "employeeID -eq '10312' -Property employeeID` just like that

Comment: Interesting I get nothing when I run either line.    So to make sure I am doing the correct thing you ask here is what I did.  I imported AD Module then either of your lines then I put pause just so I could see output.  When I run then all I see is press Enter to continue.   Right?

Comment: @ShawnIT Are you sure its `employeeid` and not `employeeNumber`? `Get-ADUser -Filter "employeeNumber -eq '10312' -Property employeeNumber`?

Comment: I verified it is the number that is visible in the Attribute Editor tab employeeID

Comment: @ShawnIT Is there white space in AD then? I'm running out of ideas. `"'$(Get-Aduser accountthathasid -properties employeeid | select -expand employeeid)'"`

Comment: no white space in gui.  If I run command I get error.  I replaced accountthathasid with their Samaccountname.  Error says " Cannot process argument because the value of argument "obj" is null."  Ill work some more on it tomorrow at work.  I wish I could just show you what im doing.  At this point I feel that the code should work and I am leaving out something.  Thanks for all your help tonight!

Comment: what you expected it true.  The EmployeeID shows in the gui but not when you Write-Output all of the Get-ADuser results.  I have no clue why this is.  Do you have any idea?

Comment: @ShawnIT I hate to thrown in the towel but I dont know what else to try. Is this a permissions thing? Are you using different accounts to view and process in powershell? Do you see it when you do this: `Get-Aduser accountthathasid -properties *` or is it empty still?

Comment: This is interesting.  ALL of the users info shows except their EmployeeID and EmployeeNumber are blank.  I went in and changed their EmployeeID and EmployeeNumber thinking that maybe there was an issue with their records and changing the info may help but no go.  I tested running the script with 2 different domain admin accounts and a account that has enterprise admin.  I dont know what is left to try.   This "should" work......

Comment: as you suspected the problem was with my environment after all.  I was chatting with someone from Microsoft (I think) and was asked how many DCs we have. We have 10 DCs and once narrow the server down with Get-ADUser -server *PDC Name* everything just worked.  Ive worked on this for days and I EXTREMELY appreciate you sticking with me though it all!  I dont know what causes this behavior but Im glad its working!

Answer (score 0):

I'm willing to bet that the whole issue you're running into is that Get-ADUser is returning no user objects.

```
<Previous answer removed>
```

**Edit:** Ok, I give up, this makes no sense. I now can not find my own user by looking for it by EmployeeID. I think there may be some issues searching by employeeID because this returns nothing:

```
$me = get-aduser $env:USERNAME -Properties EmployeeID
Get-ADUser -filter "EmployeeID -eq '$($me.EmployeeID)'" -Properties EmployeeID
```

I verified that `$me` does in fact contain my ADUser object info, including my EmployeeID. I thien tried:

```
Get-ADUser -filter "UserPrincipalName -eq '$($me.UserPrincipalName)'"
```

This did work, so I am sure that my format works. At this point, I withdraw and wish you luck.

Comment: Ok so ran your example.  I did change the domain to reflect my domain and I added  "Import-Module ActiveDirectory" and I get no errors but nothing moves either.  This is driving nuts. Did I forget to do something?

Comment: Mad do you just have a typo `EmployeeID-eq` <--? `Get-ADUser -filter "EmployeeID -eq '$($me.EmployeeID)'"` works just fine for me and your other line of code